# Can I ask my university for compensation because they made errors on my transcript, which caused rejection when I applied for jobs?

Tags: transcript-of-records

What can I do about my graduate official transcripts incorrectly stating my degree? It stated that I was conferred a BS which is an undergraduate degree, and it also gave the wrong degree program that I received.

A copy was sent to me which I got extra as it was a sealed copy and one was sent out to a prospective employer that I got turned down for the job it went to. During this time period I had a death of my parents and was named executor of their estate. So I didn't worry what the school had sent since it was sent as an official transcript I had to trust the system. However years later after I had scanned my copy into my computers local drive back then I never questioned it or thought to read it since I did actually graduated and this transcript was received after my graduation date; so basically I trusted the University system since I was highly busy and grieving during this time and going forward.

It came to my attention a few days ago when I had applied for a job with US government and decided to ask the gatekeeper of hiring department why was my application turned down. She told me on the last page of my official graduate transcript it stated the correct date of graduation but the wrong degree and wrong class/school that I conferred she said it was for an undergraduate degree and I needed a graduate degree. I'm hurt since all these years I was getting turned down was due to my University making this big error on my transcript that they signed off on as official. Can I be compensated?

They did send another correct transcript after I had called and had to beg for it and argue about it being official transcript with the Registrar's signature and all but their point was that it was on their old software system so they were not technically liable for the error since they can't prove what date I paid for this official transcript.

Comment: So, this happened years ago and was recently corrected. Yes?

Comment: This seems like a better fit for [law.se].

Comment: Is the current version of the transcript correct?

Comment: Please write a meaningful title.

Comment: Can we assume that you are in the US ? Please add the country tag if possible.

Comment: "**A copy was sent to me which I got extra as it was a sealed copy and one was sent out to a prospective employer that I got turned down for the job it went to**". So, do both copies contain the same errors ? Did you not open your **sealed copy** to verify all the info when you first got it ?

Comment: Can you estimate how many potential job offers, which you may have got but were denied due to the errors on the transcript provided by the university ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I be compensated?

We don't know have all the info, and would certainly prefer not to offer legal advice on this site.

You may want to talk to the lawyers in your country. The lawyers would be the ones who could offer you good advice on how to proceed. Your lawyers will need to prove that you have got potential job offers denied because of the errors on the transcript provided by the university.

It's hard to see how you (**alone**) could successfully ask your former university for compensation. The universities always have tons of procedures, policy, rules, regulations and of course big lawyers on their side if necessary.